# mockito stub makes no difference to test result?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm new to Mockito and working on a basic example below. If I comment out the stubbed line below the test still passes, what am I doing wrong?

I would have expected the test to fail if I remove the stubbed line as the 'serviceUnderTest' would then not return the correct result from the underlying call to the 'doSomething' method in the mocked dependency?

```
public class MyTest {

private MyService serviceUnderTest;

@Mock
private MyHelper mockedDependency;

@Before
public void doBeforeEachTestCase() 
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    serviceUnderTest = new MyServiceImpl();
    serviceUnderTest.setMyHelper(mockedDependency);
}

@Test
public void test1()
{
    try
    {
        SomeObject someObject = null;

        // create my stub
        stub(mockedDependency.doSomething("123", false, false)).thenReturn(someObject);

        // run the implementation
        ServiceResult serviceResult = serviceUnderTest.anotherMethod("123", false, false);

        // check the state
        assertNotNull(serviceResult);

        // check the behaviour of the mock
        verify(mockedDependency).doSomething("123", false, false);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        fail();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: AM not aware of mocito.. but when you stub verify may not catch it..

Comment: A note: catching exceptions just to throw `fail()` is not a very good practice. Just let the test throw the exception.

Comment: using when() does not resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

At the time you do your stubbing, `someObject` is null.  So you're setting up the mock to return `null` from that method.

But `null` is the default value that a mock will return anyway, from a method that returns an object.  Your stubbing actually makes no difference.  Note that there are some exceptions to this rule.

- If a method returns a collection, then the default return will be an empty collection.
- If a method returns one of the wrapper types, then the default return will be zero or false, rather than null.
- The `toString` method returns the name of the mock.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my own misunderstanding of Mockito!

The test was always passing because of the irrelevance of the stubbed method in this case. The stubbed method is used to provide a response to a method call in the service under test, it does not mean that the actual method that I'm verifying at the end of the test is not called.

The method I'm verifying is called in the service under test and the stub makes no difference to this, hence it passes.

Answer (score -1):

At first, if it's a pure unit test you can get rid of `@Before` section using `@RunWith` and `@InjectMocks` annotations. They will handle the initialization phase.

Second, you don't nee to put `try-catch` blocks, you can just declare the `Exception` in your testMethod.

And it's better to use `when()` instead of `stub()`, like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) public class MyTest {

@Mock
private MyHelper mockedDependency;

@InjectMocks
private MyService serviceUnderTest;

@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    SomeObject someObject = null;

    // create my stub
    when(mockedDependency.doSomething("123", false, false)).thenReturn(someObject);

    // run the implementation
    ServiceResult serviceResult = serviceUnderTest.anotherMethod("123", false, false);

    // check the state
    assertNotNull(serviceResult);

    // check the behaviour of the mock
    verify(mockedDependency).doSomething("123", false, false);
}}
```

In your case line `when(mockedDependency.doSomething` is not important - test is checking the desired behaviour of `MyServiceImpl` anyway.

Comment: doesn't work - when I comment out the 'when' line in your answer the test still passes?

Comment: strange - usually you should get NullPointerException; if your test passes it means `doSomething()` is executed, but you better check it  with debug

Comment: in your suggestion above you don't inject or set the mockedDependency object into the serviceUnderTest object? how can the service call it if this is not done?

Comment: I suggested it's a constructor argument - it this case it would be injected automatically, otherwise you should use setter.
But more important that you're returning `null` in `when()` condition - and it will be returned anyway, even without `when()` - tha't why your test is still working. Usually we use `when()` if `SomeObject` is not `null`.